# XSS clean in kohana 3.1

Tags: php, kohana

I see documentation of using xss clean for kohana old version
http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/security

But how to achieve this in kohana 3.1 
using htmlpurifier 
and alternative of

```
$this->input->get('my_var','default_value', true);
```

Comment: You never need to modify the data from get. You need to sanitize the data during output with `HTML::chars()`. And access the get variables using `$_GET` directly.

Comment: `$this->request->query()` is better ;)

Comment: @biakaveron: or `$this->request->param()`. In some reason never used it. My bad.

Comment: @^ I am using ckeditor. 
So I want to allow user to have some html tags. 
but using query , will remove it right ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rasmus proposed removing XSS blacklisting from Kohana for sake of escaping the output with `htmlspecialchars() - HTML::chars()` or using HTMLpurifier in case you really need to let some HTML in.

Since 3.1, Security doesn't have the `xss_clean()` method by default, you'll have to install [shadowhand's HTMLpurifier](https://github.com/shadowhand/purifier) module for securing input strings (by adding the submodule from github, putting it in modules and enabling it in bootstrap).

The module itself will override default Security class and add the `xss_clean()` method which uses [HTMLpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for escaping. There is also a config file for the module where you can set everything up on your application level. No input escaping is done "automatically" for many reasons; overhead, consistency, etc.

As Request was pretty much rewritten in this version to match the RFC 2616 and get even more powerful HMVC, you'll be accessing your query string vars with `Request::query()` [ `$this->request->query()` inside of your controllers ], but there is still no escaping done on that side (each request can have it's own headers, POST, GET, etc.)

The easiest way for you to escape the current POST vars would be to do:

```
$safe = Arr::map('Security::xss_clean', $this->request->post());
```

P.S.
Don't pay too much attention on nonsense written here about `$this->request->param()`, it's only for accessing the matched Route's parameters, not your GET or POST vars.

Answer (score 3):

HTMLPurifier module for the Kohana Framework:
https://github.com/shadowhand/purifier

Load de module in bootstrap and test:

```
$my_test = '<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = \'http://google.com\'"></a>';
echo Security::xss_clean($my_test);
```

Comment: do you really know php, what are you passing to that method?

Comment: echo Security::xss_clean($my_test);

Comment: you should have written so in your answer :)